# graphql apollographql validation errors (nested with error obj)

Tags: validation, graphql, apollo-server

In the event of a graphql schema validation error, I get this object `error.errors: []` instead of errors :[]

[image]

Here is a sample server

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require("apollo-server");

new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: gql`
    type Query {
      hello: String
    }
  `,
  resolvers: {
    Query: {
      hello: () => "world"
    }
  }
})
.listen()
.then(({ url }) => console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be something GraphQL Playground does if the response code is anything other than 200. I'm not sure if what you're seeing is expected behavior for Playground, but there is a related issue [here](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-playground/issues/898). Either way, if you open your network tab and look at the actual response from the server, it's formatted as expected (i.e. it's an object with an `errors` property).